# Show message on Python

Tags: tkinter, pygame

I am working on a recognition project using multiples devices. I am coding on python to develop the system and i want to show the recognized gesture in a screen. However, I tried to develop the message using Pygame but I am getting a error message since the screen is running in another thread. Same for Tkinter. Here the code that work but it gets stuck because the mainloop():

```
from mttkinter import mtTkinter
import time
import threading


class TScreen(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(TScreen, self).__init__()
        self.text = "Welcome"
        self.time = 3500
        self.master = master

    def run(self):
        #master.update_idletasks()
        #master.update()
        w = mtTkinter.Message(self.master, text=self.text)
        w.config(bg='lightgreen', font=('times', 24, 'italic'))
        w.pack()

    def draw_text(self, value):
        self.time = 3500
        self.text = value

if __name__ == '__main__':

    master = mtTkinter.Tk()
    t = TScreen(master)
    t.start()
    master.mainloop()
    print("Next step")
    t.draw_text("New Text")
```

I just want to show a big message after the real-time recognition, so I was thinking to have a thread that can control it and just send the text to be showed. It looks simple.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code little bit match you answer

```
from Tkinter import *

def onclick():
    pass

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello.....")
text.insert(END, "Bye Bye.....")
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```